# Change Netbeans Platform Main Window Background Color

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, rcp

I'm building a Netbeans Platform application for the first time. I'm looking for a way to change the background color of the main window (the window which has the menubar & toolbar). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just go: *Tools -> Options -> Fonts&Colors -> Syntax (Tab) -> Default (List) -> Background (Field)*  and then choose a Color.